# boost::property_tree::ptree serializing and deserializing

Tags: c++, boost

I am reading the xml file and storing into boost::property_tree::ptree pt(object).

I am trying to serialize this ptree object using the method `serialize()` defined in ptree_serialization.hpp

```
boost::property_tree::serialize(ar,pt,1);
```

When i use above code i get the error as;

```
boost/serialization/collections_save_imp.hpp:64:9: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘ar << boost::serialization::make_nvp(const char*, T&) [with T = const std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >]((* &((boost::iterator_facade<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> >::const_iterator, std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >, boost::bidirectional_traversal_tag, const std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >&, int>*)(& boost::operator++ [with I = boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> >::const_iterator, V = std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >, TC = boost::bidirectional_traversal_tag, R = const std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >&, D = int, typename boost::detail::postfix_increment_result<I, V, R, TC>::type = boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> >::const_iterator]((*(boost::iterator_facade<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> >::const_iterator, std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >, boost::bidirectional_traversal_tag, const std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >&, int>*)(& it)), 0)))->boost::iterator_facade<I, V, TC, R, D>::operator* [with Derived = boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> >::const_iterator, Value = std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >, CategoryOrTraversal = boost::bidirectional_traversal_tag, Reference = const std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >&, Difference = int, boost::iterator_facade<I, V, TC, R, D>::reference = const std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >&]()))’
```

Could you please let me know if i am doing something wrong. Could you please let me know if we can serialize the xml parsed property ptree object.

Comment: could you tell us how you defined `ar` and `pt`?

Comment: ar can be either iarchive or oarchive object.   pt is declared as  boost::property_tree::ptree pt;

Comment: i am not expert in this area. `boost::property_tree::ptree pt(object)` seems lack of template: `<class Key, class Data, class KeyCompare>`. i think `serialize` needs a `basic_ptree` type for second argument according to its source code: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/boost/property_tree/ptree_serialization.hpp , Also see: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1818/ . see if they help

Answer (score 2):

You should use the archive interface as intended: [doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/serialization/doc/archives.html)

```
ar << pt;
```

or

```
ar >> pt;
```

The version is as configured using `BOOST_CLASS_VERSION(Type, version)` but that's in the implementation of Property Tree

Also remember to

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree_serialization.hpp>
```

Comment: i am getting below error when used ar << pt                                        error: request for member ‘serialize’ in ‘val’, which is of non-class type ‘boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> >*’

Comment: It says you're serializing a pointer. (This might be normal). I _think_ you are missing the include (see the answer text). You ***could*** try `ar << *pt` though

Comment: I included #include <boost/property_tree/ptree_serialization.hpp> and still i am getting below error  error: ‘struct boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> >’ has no member named ‘serialize’